# A basic question about uniform convergence equivalence

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

### Attempt:

Suppose $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to f on $B$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. By definition of supremum, we know there is an $N$ such that:

$$ d_N - \epsilon < |f_N(x) - f(x) | $$

for all $x \in B$. Now, by hypothesis, we know there is some $M$ so that if $n>M$ then $|f_n(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon $. Can we assume that $N>M$??? If so, then we have

$$ d_N - \epsilon < |f_N(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon \implies d_N < \epsilon $$

Now, here I got stuck in trying to prove that $|d_n| < \epsilon$. Am I on the right track?

As for the other direction, if $d_n \to 0$ then for any $\epsilon >0$, can find some $N$ so that if $n>M$, then

$$ |d_n| < \epsilon $$

which means that there is an $N$ so that for all $n>N$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all
$x \in B$ so $f_n $ converges uniformly to f in $B$. So this direction is a lot easier than previous direction. How to tackle the first direction?

Comment: There is nothing to prove This is the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: Why the downvote? An explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the forward direction, I think introducing the $N$ is unnecessary. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since  $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $B$, there is some positive integer $M$, such that for all integers $n \geq M$, and all $x \in B$, we have
\begin{align}
|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon.
\end{align}
In other words, $\epsilon$ is an upper bound for the set $\{|f_n(x)- f(x)| \, \, x \in B\}$. Hence, it is also $\geq$ to the supremum (by definition of supremum being the least upper bound). Hence, $d_n \leq \epsilon$.

In other words, we have shown that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $M$ such that for all $n \geq M$, we have $0 \leq d_n \leq \epsilon$ (first inequality is clear). In other words, $d_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: this is perfect!

Comment: the other direction is correct no?

Comment: @ILoveMath yea it's right. So, as you can see, the uniformity in convergence is obtained by taking a supremum over all $x$ (if you think about what the supremum is actually doing somemore, this little lemma becomes almost extremely intuitively obvious). If anything, the supremum changes a $< \epsilon$ to $\leq \epsilon$, but of course this doesn't matter.

Comment: Now I see. What if the sup of those differences is bounded by a a difference $|a_n - a_m|$ of (a_n) convergent sequence. How do we prove it is uniformly convergent on some $A$? I will post this as a new question instead and show my thought

Comment: @ILoveMath as stated, the question is not precise enough for me to answer (it seems like what you said is different from what you wrote). But sure, ask a different question.

Comment: This is what I meant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651253/proving-that-f-n-converges-uniformly-on-a