# Proving that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $A$.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

### try:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. $(a_n)$ convergent means that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy sequence so that we can find $N$ with $n,m > N$ and satisfying $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$. By definition of sup, we have that

$$ |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in A} |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq |a_n-a_m| < \epsilon $$

so if we put $m=N+1$ and call $g(x) = f_{N+1}(x)$ then we observe that for all $n>N$ we obtain

$$ |f_n(x) - g(x) | < \epsilon $$

for all $x \in A$ meaning that $f_n $ converges uniformly to g(x) in A as was to be shown.

IS this correct?

Comment: It can't be, because your $g$ is $f_{N+1}$, but $N$ depends on $\epsilon$. So you've shown that "$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists g \dots$" when you should have shown "$\exists g, \forall \epsilon > 0 \dots$".

Comment: I think this problem can be fixed if we choose m=n+1 and so f_m would be the g

Comment: @peek-a-boo how do we construct then such a g?

Comment: @James that wouldn't work either, because the function $g$ (which I called $f$ in my answer) should be chosen before anything else (before $\epsilon, N, m, n$, etc) It has to be the pointwise limit of the $f_n$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume in your question the $f_n$'s are functions $A \to \Bbb{R}$. But all that is needed is for the target space to be any complete metric space. Notice that part of your proof shows in particular shows that for every $x \in A$ the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{R}$. Since $\Bbb{R}$ is complete, this sequence of numbers has a limit. Call it $f(x)$.

Thus, we have a pointwise limit $f: A \to \Bbb{R}$. I claim now that the convergence $f_n \to f$ is also uniform. For this, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then, there is an $N$ such that for all $m,n > N$, and ALL $x \in A$,
\begin{align}
|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon.
\end{align}
Let $n \geq N$, and let $x \in A$; we shall now take the limit $m \to \infty$ in the above inequality: 
\begin{align}
\lim_{m \to \infty}|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| &\leq \lim_{m \to \infty} \epsilon\\
\left| \lim_{m \to \infty}(f_n(x) - f_m(x))\right| & \leq \epsilon \\
\left| f_n(x) - f(x)\right| & \leq \epsilon,
\end{align}
where in the second step, I moved the limit inside the absolute value because $|\cdot|$ is a continuous function, so we can pull limits in and out.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, a sequence of functions which satisfies this condition is called "uniformly Cauchy on $A$". So one memorable way to state this result is that if $A$ is any non-empty set, and $X$ is a complete metric space (for example Banach space, or real/complex numbers), and $\{f_n: A \to X\}$ is a sequence of functions, then $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly Cauchy on $A$ if and only if $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $A$.

Comment: Thanks! I have question tho: Pointwise convergence is $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N such that \forall x \in A ... $ and uniform is $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N such that  ...\forall x \in A $

Comment: Why do you have the universal quantifier before $|f_n - f_m|<\epsilon$? Isn't is just point wise convergence what you have proved?

Comment: @ILoveMath Pointwise convergence is $\forall x \in A, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb{N}, \forall n \geq N \dots$ Uniform convergence is $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb{N}, \forall x \in A, \forall n \geq N, \dots$  I started with $\epsilon > 0$, then I found an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ (from the uniform Cauchyness) such that $\forall m,n \geq N$ and $\forall x \in A, \dots$. Then, I took a limit over $m$. So, that means I've shown $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb{N}, \forall x \in A, \forall n \geq N \dots$, which is precisely uniform convergence.